# I'm unable to access k8's Service through Postman

Tags: scala, kubernetes, akka-http

I created a simple scala application, that uses akkaHttp to add user data and get user data, akkaHttp is running on "localhost" and has port "8080".

`Http().newServerAt("localhost", 8080).bind(route)`

After that I create a "deployment" and "service" given below:

deployment.yaml

```
`apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-deployment

spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-label
  template:
    metadata:
      name: docker-pod
      labels:
        app: docker-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: docker-container
          image: akkahttp-k8s:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
`
```

service.yaml

```
`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: docker-service

spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: docker-label
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 32100`
```

My service and deployment are in "running" state and showing no error.

pods:

```
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
docker-deployment-79756959c6-rdknq    1/1     Running   0          6s
docker-deployment-79756959c6-thjzt    1/1     Running   0          6s
```

service:

```
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
docker-service    NodePort    10.103.170.1    <none>        8080:32100/TCP   4m35s
```

But when I try to access the service through the "Postman"  it throughs an error " `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.49.2:32100` ".
When I tried to use " port-forward docker-deployment-79756959c6-rdknq 8080:8080 " then I can interact with my pod successfully through postman using " `http://localhost:8080` ". Why I'm unable to interact with my pod through service ? where I'm doing mistake ?.
Kindly help me to deal with this issue.

Comment: If a loadbalander exists within your environment change NodePort to LoadBalancer otherwise you'll be able to connect through your node's IP address at - https://<node-ip>:32100

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Akka HTTP and Java|Scala **but** I wonder whether you're use of `localhost` is causing a problem? Presumably `Http().newServerAt("localhost", 8080).bind(route)` is being containerised and, if so, the server won't be exposed beyond the container. Instead you should probably use `0.0.0.0`. You can test this by running the container locally, exposing `8080` and trying to access it. You can also test by `kubectl port-forward deployment/docker-deployment 8080:8080` and trying to access the server on your host's port 8080. I suspect neither will work.

Comment: @Elazar  I tried with LoadBalancer as well but it doesn't work , Facing same issue, Ingress also didn't solved my problem .

Comment: @DazWilkin  I replace "localhost" with " 0.0.0.0 " but it also doesn't work, and kubectl  port-forward deployment/docker-deployment 8080:8080 , As I mentoned the port-forward is working and this make me able to add or remove data using postman. I want to access it through service but I'm unable to access the service through postman.

Comment: Your question will get more answers on ServerFault I believe.

Comment: I tried replicating this on my k8s cluster and this image doesn't exist.

Comment: Good diagnosing! OK, when you create a `Service` you should **not** specify `nodePort` as you want Kubernetes to allocate a NodePort for you(r service). Retain the (Service's) `port` and (Deployment's) `targetPort` and, when you apply the Service, a NodePort will be assigned. You need to check which NodePort is assigned and then access the Service using a Node IP and the assigned NodePort.

Comment: Also, You're allocating port `8080` to the server when you `Http().newServerAt("localhost", 8080).bind(route)` but your Deployment **incorrectly** uses `80` for the `containerPort`. It should be `8080`. And then the Service (!) `targetPort` should be `8080` too.

Comment: Thank you Guys especially @DazWilkin , the problem was related with contaimerPort, targetPort and the port on which my Http is running. Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a generic container that listens on `8080`:

https://github.com/kubernetes-up-and-running/kuard

`deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-label
  template:
    metadata:
      name: docker-pod
      labels:
        app: docker-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: docker-container
          image: gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

**NOTE** `containerPort: 8080`

and `service.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: docker-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: docker-label
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

**NOTE** `targetPort: 8080` (matches the Pod's port which is the container's port)

Then:

```bash
NAMESPACE="75488823"

kubectl create namespace ${NAMESPACE}

kubectl apply --filename=./deployment.yaml \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE}

kubectl apply --file=./service.yaml \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

Then access the service using `kubectl port-forward`

```bash
kubectl port-forward deployment/docker-deployment \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
8080:8080
```

And:

```bash
curl \
--silent \
--get \
--output /dev/null \
--write-out '%{response_code}' \
http://localhost:8080
```

Should yield `200` (success)

Then access the services using any (!) nodes' IP address. You may need to determine the `{HOST}` value for yourself. You want any node's public IP address.

```bash
# Get any nodes' IP
HOST=$(\
  kubectl get nodes \
  --output=jsonpath="{.items[0].status.addresses[0].address}"

# Get the service's `nodePort`
PORT=$(\
  kubectl get service/docker-service \
  --namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
  --output=jsonpath="{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}")

curl \
--silent \
--get \
--output /dev/null \
--write-out '%{response_code}' \
http://${HOST}:${PORT}
```

Should also yield `200` (success).

Tidy:

```bash
kubectl delete namespace/${NAMESPACE}
```